# Swiftmailer + Symfony3.4: "Connection could not be established with host xx.xx.xx.xx"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to connect to smtp server which is located in my local machine.
Ping ok, telnet works fine, but from Symfony app i get "Connection could not be established with host .. "

Docker with ubuntu 18. PHP7.3

Below you have my actual configuration, but What i also tried was mixing smtp with ssl/465, tls/587, changing smtp  to mail and try with all 3 enc/port configurations, and same thing with sendmail.

None of these worked. I used SwiftMailerLogger, nothing usefull came up, just that connection could not be established. In some configurations i got 'Connection refused' after main message.

My app is placed on docker machine, smtp daemon is in different location on same machine, but i also tried to do all configurations outside docker, still no luck.

Did anyone try to use swiftmailer with local smtp daemon?

My configuration:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: local_ip
mailer_user: user
mailer_password: pass
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_port: 25
```

Comment: I would assume this to be a docker issue, and better asked on serverfault

Comment: @Jakumi i tried to connect from outside docker as well as i described in my question, still no luck, but thanks ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because other users won't be able to have enough information and context to debug a 
networking issue.

Comment: @yivi edited, solved ;)

Comment: If you've a solution for your case please don't put it inside your question but use the answer section instead.

Comment: @gp_sflover ok, done

Answer (score 0):

Succeed!

First of all, auth-mode : plain, and :

```
stream-options:
    ssl:
        allow_self_signed: true
        verify_peer: false
```

Still using tls and 587 port.